# IEnumerable - exclude using an array

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a new IEnumerable by using an array parameter to exclude values.

For instance, below is an example of how I imagine it would look.

```
   class Item
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
   }
```

IEnumerable looks like this:

```
item1 {id = 1}
item2 {id = 2}
item3 {id = 3}
```

I want to create a new IEnumerable but exclude the id numbers in the array.

**Made up code to suggest idea:**

```
Int32[] arrayList = {1,2};
var newIEnumerable = _exisitingIEnumerable.Where(o => (o.id NOT IN arrayList));
```

Comment: Is this what you want: `var newIEnumerable = _exisitingIEnumerable.Where(o => !arrayList.Contains(o.id));`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have tried to make my question clearer.

Comment: Henrik was first with the correct answer but I couldn't mark it as such. I see the question was down voted. It can be ruthless on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your question again, when the element type of `_exisitingIEnumerable` is not the same as that of `arrayList`, you will need to use `Where` to filter out the elements of `arrayList`

```
_exisitingIEnumerable.Where(o => !arrayList.Contains(o.Id))
```

**Original answer:**

```
_exisitingIEnumerable.Except(arrayList)
```

will return the **distinct** elements from `_exisitingIEnumerable` that are not in `arrayList`

If you need duplicates, you can use

```
_exisitingIEnumerable.Where(o => !arrayList.Contains(o))
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the approach you suggested in the question? You can use `Where` and check if the array contains the value. Below the example using List as a target collection:

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };

var result = new List<int>(myList.Where(n => !myArray.Contains(n)));
```